# Удаление определенного количества байт с конца файла shell

Tags: linux, shell

Необходимо средствами shell удалить с конца файла N-ое количество символов.

Использовал `truncate -s $(( $(stat -c '%s' $file) - $n )) $file`.

Проект переехал на BusyBox. `truncate` там нет. 
Есть идеи как еще это можно реализовать?

Comment: Если файл короткий, то переписыванием в новый файл `dd` но вообще это мягко говоря не оптимально

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. можно скопировать нужное количество байт (рассчитать ведь не сложно) от начала первого файла во второй с помощью программы `dd`:

   ```
   $ dd if=первый.файл of=второй.файл bs=1 count=количество
   ```
2. можно пересобрать *busybox* с необходимой функциональностью: https://github.com/akretion/busybox-remastering/blob/master/coreutils/truncate.c

Answer (score 2):

Написать собственный truncate на C, откомпилировать, таскать с собой.

Объясняю, почему C, а не питон или еще какая пакость - truncate - это один единственный системный вызов. Так что никакого рантайма за собой тащить не надо.